# AlamofireObjectMapper returning empty jsonarray

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, objectmapper

My question is: Why does my method return an Empty json array with `.responseArray`?

I have the following JSON coming from my REST-API:

```
[
   {
       "id": 1,
       "title": "Crazy",
       "startDate": "2016-07-16 22:00:00.0",
       "endDate": "2016-07-17 03:00:00.0",
       "location": "Crazy",
       "description": "Crazy",
       "avatar": "base64"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Crazy title",
        "startDate": "2016-07-16 22:00:00.0",
        "endDate": "2016-07-17 03:00:00.0",
        "location": "Crazy",
        "description": "Something",
        "avatar": "base64"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Crazy",
        "startDate": "2016-07-16 22:00:00.0",
        "endDate": "2016-07-17 03:00:00.0",
        "location": "Crazy",
        "description": "Crazy",
        "avatar": "base64"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Crazy",
        "startDate": "2016-07-16 22:00:00.0",
        "endDate": "2016-07-17 03:00:00.0",
        "location": "Crazy",
        "description": "Crazy",
        "avatar": "base64"
}]
```

The json is an array with multiple objects as you can see.

I use AlamofireObjectMapper to map the json as an object, but it's returning me an empty array:

```
 func getEventFromApiWebService(completionHandler: (event: [Event]) -> ()){
    Alamofire.request(ApiRouter.Get("/events"))
        .validate()
        .responseArray(completionHandler: { (response: Response<[Event], NSError>) in

            //Attempt to print result value which returns empty Array
            let eventArray = response.result.value
            print(eventArray!)

            completionHandler(event: response.result.value!)

        })
}
```

The following code does work with .responseJSON:

```
    func test(){
    Alamofire.request(ApiRouter.Get("/events"))
        .responseJSON { response  in

            print(response.result.value!)
    }
}
```

However no mapping is happening here.

The event class:

```
import ObjectMapper
import RealmSwift

class Event: Object, Mappable {

    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var eventID = 0
    dynamic var title: String? = nil
    dynamic var startDate: NSDate? = nil
    dynamic var endDate: NSDate? = nil
    dynamic var location: String? = nil
    dynamic var desc: String? = nil
    dynamic var avatar: NSData? = nil

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    required convenience init?(_ map: Map) {
        self.init()

        if map["id"].value() == nil {
            return nil
        }
        if map["title"].value() == nil {
            title = ""
        }
        if map["startDate"].value() == nil {
            startDate = nil
        }
        if map["endDate"].value() == nil {
            endDate = nil
        }
        if map["location"].value() == nil {
            location = ""
        }
        if map["description"].value() == nil {
            desc = ""
        }
        if map["avatar"].value() == nil {
            avatar = nil
        }
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        self.eventID        <- map["id"]
        self.title          <- map["title"]
        self.startDate      <- map["startDate"]
        self.endDate        <- map["endDate"]
        self.location       <- map["location"]
        self.desc           <- map["description"]
        self.avatar         <- map["avatar"]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alamofire does not have the `responseArray` method. https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#response-serialization

Use `responseJSON` to get the JSON and convert into an array.

```
.responseJSON { response in

    guard response.result.isSuccess else
    {
          //handle error 
          return
    }
```

### Response Serialization

**Built-in Response Methods**

- response()
- responseData()
- responseString(encoding: NSStringEncoding)
- responseJSON(options: NSJSONReadingOptions)
- responsePropertyList(options: NSPropertyListReadOptions)

---

```
required convenience init?(_ map: Map) {
    self.init()
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    id    <- map["id"]
    title <- map["title"]
    startDate <- map["startDate"]
    endDate <- map["endDate"]
}
```

Comment: My bad, I'm using the extended library https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper 

Where in the code snippets they use:

Alamofire.request(.GET, URL).responseArray. 

Ill edit my library name in the question, sorry!

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep trying to find a solution, because it should work with AlamofireObjectMapper!

Comment: Do you need to import `AlamofireObjectMapper`?

Comment: Yes I do, however I found the solution! Thank you for your time in replying!

Comment: it returns empty response from server while data is coming if I make request from ARC.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the DataTypes in my event class aren't right with the JSON. 
Somewhere in the `required convenience init?(_ map: Map)` it gives me a nil and thus refusing to deserialise the entire JsonArray.

Comment: Maybe my updated answer can help you more regarding the mapping.